# Исправление ошибок большинства дистрибутивов Linux

Tags: linux, логирование

Здравствуйте! На днях, чисто в развлекательных целях я экспериментировал с различными дистрибутивами, устанавливая их один за другим и случайно наткнулся на такую чудесную софтину как [gnome-logs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Logs). Она довольно удобно сортирует системные логи и выводит самые важные сообщения на первой вкладке. Так вот, я заметил, что практически всем дистрибутивам "из коробки" присущи одни и те же ошибки. Вот самые популярные (я буду вносить правки в этот список; не стесняйтесь делиться своими ошибками и их способами исправления):

- **PAM adding faulty module/unable to dlopen: pam_kwallet**

  - в /etc/pam.d/lightdm и /etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter нужно закомментировать все строки, начинающиеся с "auth optional". Для этого добавьте символ "**#**" в начале строк.
- **Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user has read and write permissions for those files.**

  - Эта ошибка возникает только с драйверами nvidia версии выше 304 (откат драйверов на сто лет назад ради очистки логов - конечно же не решение проблемы, но может это как-то поможет).
- **Failed to start Automatically refresh installed snaps**

  - Иногда появляется, иногда пропадает.
- **[pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.**
- **nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed**

В общем, сколько я ни гуглил, мне так и не удалось исправить ни одну из них. Удивительно, что и нагуглить толком ничего не удалось. Да, я понимаю, что скорее всего эти ошибки ни на что не влияют, но по крайней мере они засоряют логи буквально в каждом дистрибутиве! Разве это нормально? Кстати, отпишитесь пожалуйста если у вас этих ошибок нет.

Comment: ну заведи репозиторий на гитхабе да и исправь все эти техдолги, тебе только спасибо скажут. p.s. у меня нет таких ошибок (ubuntu 16.04). 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed в декабре было, вполне возможно, большинство таких ошибок возникает при установке, поэтому никто и не чинит

Comment: @strangeqargo ошибок с PAM точно нет? Я ставил Ubuntu 16.04 и они были. Неужели это как-то может быть связано с железом? Не думаю... И на счёт того что они возникают при установке - нет. Эти логи генерируются и обновляются при каждом входе в систему.

Comment: точно. kwallet значит смотри

Comment: Значит дистрибутивы которые вы пробовали на всякий случай пишут в конфиги PAM все возможные в дистрибутиве модули. При том что сами модули могут и не ставят. Вычистите руками этот kwallet из /etc/pam.d/* (или где в ваших дистрибутивах настройки pam). Сам не видел ни одной подобной ошибки, правда у меня обычно gentoo

Comment: @Mike спасибо за совет! В файлах lightdm и lightdm-greeter я закомментировал все строки, начинающиеся с "auth optional" и это действительно решило проблему!

Comment: Однако остаются ещё другие ошибки, описанные выше. Плюс вот лично у меня недавно ещё одна стала регулярно вылазить: **"Failed to start Automatically refresh installed snaps"**. Есть ещё мысли по этому поводу? Неужели у всех чистые логи?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, [далеко не все вопросы можно «вписать» в принятую модель](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643/178576). кстати: удалять вопрос вовсе необязательно.

Comment: Видимо подавляющему большинству на самом деле важно, чтобы их конкретные задачи работали и если они работают, то логи вообще не смотрят (наверное, с практической т.з. *это нормально*). Поэтому разработчики не получают массовых bug reports, и не исправляют.

Comment: Лишние записи в лог быстрее изнашивают флеш-накопители, так что с ними нужно бороться

Comment: тебе дали ответ на твои вопросы, поэтому просто переделай вопрос (заголовок и вступление), чтобы он соответствовал ответу, тогда его больше людей найдет и это им будет полезно, я бы не стал удалять

Comment: @strangeqargo Если честно, я не совсем понимаю, что не так с заголовком и вступлением. Буду благодарен если посоветуешь как их улучшить. А по поводу ответов - не все же ошибки исправлены. Я буду править список по мере поступления новых ошибок/решений.